# GLUT: How to Make Sphere with radius greater than 1?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut, freeglut

I am trying to make a solar system using OpenGL for project. As I have other planets and moons too, I want to make my sun larger than radius=1, and my earth=1 since a little less than 0.18, the sphere is barely visible, and moons cannot be drawn with proper size difference.

Below is my code, if I try to make a sphere with radius > 1, it becomes donut (torus) like. Can anyone guide me on how to make spheres using gluSphere of radius > 1?

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);

GLUquadric *quad;
quad = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricDrawStyle(quad, GLU_FILL);

//Sun
glColor3f(2,1.65, 0);
glPushMatrix();
gluSphere(quad, 1, 20, 20);
glPopMatrix();

//Earth
glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
glTranslated(2.f, 0.f, 0.f);
glPushMatrix();
gluSphere(quad, 0.18, 20, 20);
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sphere is clipped by the near and far plane of the viewing volume ([Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection)). Use [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) instead of [`gluOrtho2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) and increase the distance to the near and far plane:

<s>`gluOrtho2D(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);`</s>

```cpp
glOrtho(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);
```

When using Orthographic Projection, the view space coordinates are mapped linearly to the clip space coordinates. The viewing volume is defined by 6 distances (left, right, bottom, top, near, far). The values for left, right, bottom, top, near and far define a cuboid (box). All of the geometry that is within the volume of the box is projected onto the two-dimensional viewport and is "visible". All geometry that is outside this volume is clipped.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate this.